# How to delete every second element from list in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I am trying to delete every second element in list of lists and get:

[[1,2,3,4,5],[6],[100,101,102,103],[10,11]] = [1,3,5,6,100,102,10]

First i tried to write function that prints every second element and then i have stucked.

```
takeSecond :: [a] -> [a]
takeSecond [] = []
takeSecond [a] = []
takeSecond (y:x:xs) = [x] ++ takeSecond xs
fun :: [[a]] -> [a]
fun [] = []
fun (x:xs) = (takeSecond x) ++ (fun xs)
```

Comment: Deleting each second item, is the same as taking each item of the odd position, you can slightly update the last clause of your `takeSecond` for that.

Comment: but i want to use delete or drop function

Comment: Instead of `[x] ++ takeSecond xs` you can write `x : takeSecond xs`.

Comment: Write a function that deletes every second element from *one* list, then use `concatMap` to apply that function to your list of lists and concatenate the results into a single list.

Answer (score 1):

You're close :) there is a typo in your `takeSecond` function but otherwise it should work against your input. You might be interested in a function called `concat` from the `List` module, which flattens a list of list: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/GHC-List.html#v:concat. If you don't want to use library functions and want to implement everything yourself, I would suggest you try to reimplement a function like `concat` and then pass the result of applying your function to `takeSecond` (after fixing the typo of course).

**Edit**: I took a better look, there are actually two typos. I don't want to give you the full answer because you're really close and I think it's more instructive to identify the bugs yourself (unless you want me to of course), so I will only mention that the typos are in your last 2 cases for the `takeSecond` function.